# Black screen during Whastapp call/audio

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, proximity-sensor

My proximity sensor is broken, and, Whastapp turns the screen off during call/audio. Not even power button will turn it back on.

All "solutions" out there tell me to clean the sensor. Impossible here.

How to disable this completely ?

I've tried Xposed's Disable Sensor module, entirely disabling this sensor or mocking it's values. No results.

I thought about revoking a sensor usage permission for that app, but could not find a module that has such an option

I can't remember if the problem happens during phone calls, but if the fix could be extended to this area, great

Xperia Z3

Comment: Sorry. Didn't work. Even with "Sensors" restricted on whatsapp. Wish I could send a screenshot

Comment: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AilzHUVAr7w5hV2kH2DilKG43bwh - https://1drv.ms/u/s!AilzHUVAr7w5hV6kgF-TdCKvqE89

Comment: On second thoughts, you can try applying to system apps (you can select system apps from the drop down) and select phone ( I am assuming it is phone app that is related to proximity sensor). If that doesn't help apply to all system apps. Nothing more I can suggest

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP's account has been deleted, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

Searching all over the web tonight 1/22/21 looking for an answer on how to fix this and found NOTHING. So with trial and error and a little ingenuity I developed my own solution which worked.

1. Turn on airplane mode while the black error screen for in call is opened up on your phone.
2. After the first beep notifying you the the call is losing connection the screen/app realizes it's error and reverts back to the normal state. In call screen will now be normal.
3. Turn off airplane mode immediately after the in call screen is remedied so you do not lose your call.
4. You're welcome